# LinkedList: Why there is need to declare a new struct node current? The code works perfectly fine if I use the argument head for tracking?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
int Count(struct node* head, int searchFor) {
    struct node* current = head;
    int count = 0;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->data == searchFor)
            count++;

        current = current->next;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Why there is need to declare current struct node? We would get the same result if we use head that is passed in the argument list.

```
int Count(struct node* head, int searchFor) {
    int count = 0;

    while(head != NULL) {
        if (head->data == searchFor) {
            count ++;
        } 

        head = head->next;
    }

    return count;
}
```

What is the concept behind this? Is this just for clean code or some other reason?

Comment: It's all a matter of semantics: "head" and "current" are two different concepts.

Comment: You don't need an additional `current` if all you're doing is walking the nodes. You can use a value `head` pointer without issue (honestly that pointer should be `const struct node *head` if you want to play nice. there is no reason to pass a hot pointer to a function performing a simple read-only enumeration). If there is a need to preserve the original passed in pointer value (which your algorithm does *not* demonstrate), obviously a secondary pointer is warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's the "same", they're "pointing" to the same location at the beginning.

```
struct node* current = head;
```

But after you change the current item to the next they stop pointing to the same.

```
current = current->next;
```

After this your current is not the same as head anymore, and if you need to restart you still have a reference to head in **head** pointer.

The point is what you expect when you read "head", you expect that it's pointing to the head item, right? If you change it'll make your code confuse for other programmers who end up maintaining it.

What I would suggest is to rename your parameter to **current** if you don't need to use head in this function anymore (but it's always good to have a pointer to head in some place).

```
int Count(struct node* current, int searchFor) {
    int count = 0;

    while(current != NULL) {
        if (current->data == searchFor) {
            count ++;
        } 

        current = current->next;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: But now, it's the argument name that makes no sense for the caller! Truly, the only good solution is to use two different variables for two different concepts. The optimizer will give them the same register/memory location anyway.

Comment: You still can call Count with head, not a big deal: Count(head, 10);

Answer (score 3):

It's generally done so as to preserve the original value (`head`) passed to the function since `current` is being modified and you'll lose the original pointer permanently if you modify `head` directly. But in your case, it makes no difference whether you use an extra temporary `current` or not as `head` is not needed any further in `Count()`.

It's matter of taste, really. I'd personally prefer using version with `current` as I feel it's more readable with "current" than modifying "head" directly.

Answer (score 1):

For the code you showed there is only one concept behind this: to make the code more readable.:)

When you see that head is changed then you have to be more attentive and to be sure that the code is correct. This takes more time that to understand the code.:)

Nevertheless the first code snippet has a drawback. Variable current is declare in the code block where it is not used. I would write the code the following way

```
int Count( const struct node* head, int searchFor ) 
{
    int count = 0;

    for  ( const struct node* current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next ) 
    {
        if ( current->data == searchFor ) count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Won't adding "const struct node * current = head " make the current node point to a constant node. (i.e., your can't change the value of current, right?)